# swift extension for generics array

Tags: swift, generics, extension-methods

I want to return `[S:M]` type, but the Xcode will alert `Single argument function types require parentheses`, is there any way to fix this, please help me, thanks

```
extension Array {
    func merge<S, M>() where Element == [S:M] -> [S:M] {
        var res: [S:M] = [:]
        forEach { (element) in
            element.forEach({ (obj) in
                res[obj.key] = obj.value
            })
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-> [S:M]` needs to be put before the `where` clause.

```
extension Array {
  func merge <S, M> () -> [S: M] where Element == [S: M] {
    var res: [S: M] = [:]

    self.forEach { element in
      element.forEach { obj in
        res[obj.key] = obj.value
      }
    }

    return res
  }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus True. In this case, conforming `S` to `Hashable` is redundant since it's automagically inferred from `[S: M]`. If we add it the compiler will throw a warning. 